# NodeJS - Make POST/GET request to a website that requires login

Tags: node.js, post, get, request

I am trying to make a POST or GET request to a page that requires login.

Is there a way that I can login before I make the request or a way that I can make the request if I already am logged in on my browser?

Regards, 
Alexandru Spinu

Comment: Yes, however how it is accomplished will depend on how authentication is implemented on the target server.

Comment: @KevinB - Could you please be more specific? :)

Comment: well, for example, some login systems require username/password as post params, some as get, some as auth headers, etc. Some return tokens to use in auth header, some in a special auth header, some require cookies, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little framework that I use to test my node apps. It is only one file and is rather misleadingly called [django-endpoint-test here on github](https://github.com/diversemix/django-endpoint-test) - at some stage I do plan to update this - let me know if this helps your scenario.